# Efficient Value type

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, variant

I want to create efficient and easy to use value type.
Base of the `Value` is a `boost::variant` (and `std::variant` in the future), but I'm new in it.
And I have some questions:

- In the code below, is it necessary to use recursive variant?
- Is it possible to not  inherit from the `boost::variant`? Maybe more efficient way exists?
- Do you have any comments or suggestions on the code below (it's not fully completed code, but only a draft)?

```
    class Value;

    typedef std::string                 String;
    typedef std::vector<char>           BinData;
    typedef String                      URL;
    typedef unsigned long long          UID;
    TSW_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::time_t, Time)

    typedef std::vector<Value>          ValueArray;
    typedef std::vector<String>         StringArray;
    //typedef std::pair<String, Value>    NameValue;

    typedef std::list<Value>            ValueList;
    typedef std::list<String>           StringList;
    typedef std::map<String, String>    StringStringMap;
    typedef std::map<String, Value>     NameValueMap;

    struct monostate
    {
        monostate() = default;
    };

    constexpr bool operator<(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return false; }
    constexpr bool operator>(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return false; }
    constexpr bool operator<=(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return true; }
    constexpr bool operator>=(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return true; }
    constexpr bool operator==(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return true; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(monostate, monostate) noexcept { return false; }


    typedef monostate Null;


    class Object
    {
    public:
        Object() = delete;
        Object(const Object &other) = default;
        Object(Object &&other);

        Object(const String &name);
        Object(String &&name);
        Object(const String &name, const NameValueMap &fields);
        Object(String &&name, const NameValueMap &fields);
        Object(const String &name, NameValueMap &&fields);
        Object(String &&name, NameValueMap &&fields);

        Object &operator=(const Object &other) = default;
        Object &operator=(Object &&other);

    public:
        const String &get_name() const;
        const NameValueMap &get_fields() const;

    public:
        bool operator<(const Object &other) const noexcept;
        bool operator>(const Object &other) const noexcept;
        bool operator<=(const Object &other) const noexcept;
        bool operator>=(const Object &other) const noexcept;
        bool operator==(const Object &other) const noexcept;
        bool operator!=(const Object &other) const noexcept;

    private:
        String name_;
        NameValueMap fields_;
    };


    enum class ValueType
    {
        Undefined, Null, Array, BinData, Boolean, DoubleNumber, Int64Number, String, Time, Object
    };

    // Types ordnung need to be same with ValueType ordnung.
    /// Base for the Value class
    typedef boost::variant<monostate, Null, ValueArray, BinData, bool, double, int64_t, String, Time, Object> ValueBase;


    /**
    * @brief The Value class, implements common framework value.
    *
    * This class is a container, which can store multiple values, including Values containers.
    *
    * @note
    * Class based on a variant class. It may be either boost::variant or std::variant in C++17 and higher.
    */
    class Value : public ValueBase
    {
    public:
        using ValueBase::ValueBase;
        Value() = default;
        Value(const String::value_type *v) : ValueBase(String(v)) {}

    public:
        bool is_array() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Array; }
        bool is_bool() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Boolean; }
        bool is_bindata() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::BinData; }
        bool is_double() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::DoubleNumber; }
        bool is_int64() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Int64Number; }
        bool is_null() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Null; }
        bool is_object() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Object; }
        bool is_string() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::String; }
        bool is_time() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Time; }
        bool is_undefined() const { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()) == ValueType::Undefined; }

    public:
        bool          as_bool() const  { return as<bool>(); }
        BinData       &as_bindata()  { return as<BinData>(); }
        double        as_double() const  { return as<double>(); }
        int64_t       as_int64() const  { return as<int64_t>(); }
        Object        &as_object()  { return as<Object>(); }
        String        &as_string()  { return as<String>(); }
        Time          &as_time()  { return as<Time>(); }
        ValueArray    &as_array()  { return as<ValueArray>(); }

    public:
        ValueType     value_type() const  { return static_cast<ValueType>(which()); }

    public:
        template <typename T>
        const T& as() const { return boost::get<T>(*this); }

        template <typename T>
        T& as() { return boost::get<T>(*this); }

        template <typename T>
        const T& as(const T& default_value) const { return type() == typeid(T) ? boost::get<T>(*this) : default_value; }

        template <typename T>
        T& as(const T& default_value) { return type() == typeid(T) ? boost::get<T>(*this) : default_value; }

        template <typename T> boost::optional<T> as_optional() { return boost::make_optional(type() == typeid(T), as<T>()); }

    public:
        bool operator==(const ValueBase &other) const { return ValueBase::operator==(other); }
        bool operator<(const ValueBase &other) const { return ValueBase::operator<(other); }
        bool operator>(const ValueBase &other) const { return !((*this) < other || (*this) == other); }
        bool operator<=(const ValueBase &other) const { return ((*this) < other || (*this) == other); }
        bool operator>=(const ValueBase &other) const { return !((*this) < other); }
        bool operator!=(const ValueBase &other) const { return !((*this) == other); }

    private:
        // Force compile error, prevent Variant(bool) to be called
        Value(void *) = delete;
    };
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: - I need a duplex bus to send/receive messages.
- Message is a container, contains fields and link to metadata.

- Messages serialized/deserialized in/from BSON.

- I need a `common value`.

- I need very little delays for serialization/deserialization and getting data from message fields.

Comment: This question might have been been a slightly better match for [CodeReview.SE]

Comment: In the case of deserialization, you could mimic the design of protobuf and do lazy conversions from the underlying binary buffer. (But _please_ don't mimic the API interface!)

Comment: 2sehe: Thanks for the link. I haven't knew about this site.

Comment: I don't like protobuf. I use ejdb as a sirealizer/deserializer and base, zeromq ROUTER/DEALER as a bottom layer.

Comment: If I complete this project, it will be open source in the future.

Comment: @A.N. nobody likes protobuf :) I was merely taking it as an example for a specific optimization

Comment: Thanks, I'll look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks okay to me.

You can do without recursive variants IFF your standard library implementation allows instantiation of the container classes for incomplete types.

I'd note that since everything is tied to the base-class publicly, there is nothing about the implementation that can change without also changing the (binary) interface. Therefore I'd surely implement all the members inline so that the compiler will optimize them even without LTO.

It is not clear to me what `to_X` members do (possibly just `a<X>` but possibly something else depending on `can_convert()`?). If it's just a wrap around `as_<>` I'd rename them `as_X()` etc.

You might also want to add `optional<>`-like members like

```
template <typename T> T const& get_value_or(T const& default_value) const;
```

And possibly

```
template <typename T> optional<T> get() const;
// with boost optional you can prevent a copy²:
template <typename T> optional<T const&> get() const;
```

This enables code like:

```
if (auto& s = value.get<String>()) {
     std::cout << "The string value is '" << *s << "'\n";
} else {
     std::cout << "Value has no string value\n";
}
```

---

¹ this is not - yet - standard specified. You can always use Boost Container instead which promises this, as well as non-allocating construction

² just make sure you do not allow the operation on a rvalue, to remove a predictable class of errors, so e.g.

```
template <typename T> optional<T const&> get()&& = delete;
```

Comment: I have appended implementation.

Comment: @A.N. I'm confused about your implementation. Why does the comment reference `value_`? Are you going to pimpl it? That's gonna hurt the optimizer. Like I said, I'd define the members _inline_

Comment: value_ is an old piece  of code. This is only a draft. First variant with a pImpl didn't satisfy me.

Comment: Okay. Now I'm at a loss what `can_convert` is for. And why the functions are (mis)named confusingly. But bottomline: the variant works and could be considered lightweight.  With the few remarks I have made in the answer text.

Comment: I think, `can_convert` is useless now. Better name: `is_conversible_to`. I'll remove it or rewrite as a template.

Comment: > You can do without recursive variants If your standard library implementation allows instantiation of the container classes for incomplete types.

Good. Is `recursive_variant` an addition for compatibility? gcc, clang and MSVC STLs support instantiation for incomplete types.

Comment: `recursive_wrapper<>` is a layer of indirection that allows use with any element type that does _not_ allow incomplete types. If your containers don't require it, be happy, but that doesn't make `recursive_wrapper<>` obsolete by any stretch. It's not a compatibility thing, it's an extensibility feature.

Comment: The Value has been fixed according to your suggestions. Thank you. You can check, if you want.

Comment: Another thing that caught my eye just now: instead of having `Object` to create a "named" value, you could just make `NameValueMap` used as `Object`. In effect, `NameValueMap` of one element _is_ a named value, and now you have two places in which to name values: `NameValueMap` as well as `Object`. I'd think a JSON-like tree is more intuitive (see e.g. https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/master/json.hpp#L37)

Comment: This is better version of the previous Interface: if they want to use it, this version will be more useful. Previously Object was a typedef to a NameValueMap. But it's not very handy. I need named object with an easy understanding, where is a name.

Comment: JSON and BSON always have named objects, and serializer interface looks like this: `void append_field(const String &name, const Object &data);`

Comment: And yes, Value can contain named objects (named NamedValueMap).

Comment: It's my fault. I understood it, when have started make deserialization. Fixed.